# PHP array of objects traversing

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, recursion

I have this array of objects:

Array A:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "type":"title",
      "data": "Title goes here"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "type":"repeat"
      "number":3,
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "type":"media"
      "data": "path to media"
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "type":"close_repeat"
   },
   {
      "id":5,
      "type":"repeat"
      "number":3,
   },
   {
      "id":6,
      "type":"title",
      "data": "Title goes here"
   },
   {
      "id":7,
      "type":"repeat"
      "number":2,
   },
   {
      "id":8,
      "type":"text"
      "data": "Text goes here"
   },
   {
      "id":9,
      "type":"close_repeat"
   },
   {
      "id":10,
      "type":"close_repeat"
   },
   {
      "id":11,
      "type":"cover",
      "data": "Cover data goes here"
   },
]
```

And I want to transfer it into:

Array B

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "type":"title",
      "data": "Title goes here",
      "repeat":1
   },

   {
      "id":3,
      "type":"media"
      "data": "path to media",
      "repeat":1
   },
   {
      "id":6,
      "type":"title",
      "data": "Title goes here",
      "repeat":3
   },
   {
      "id":8,
      "type":"text"
      "data": "Text goes here",
      "repeat":6
   },
   {
      "id":11,
      "type":"cover",
      "data": "Cover data goes here",
      "repeat":1
   },
]
```

The idea is that Array A (the original) has two special objects of type `repeat` and `close_repeat`. Objects of type `repeat` have an extra attribute called `number`. The value of this attribute specifies how many times the objects between `repeat` and `close_repeat` should be repeated. Further more, `repeat` and `close_repeat` can be nested so that if we strat `repeat` then before closing it we start another `repeat` then the objects that follows have to be repeated based on the multiples of the two repeats. So in the Array A, object with `id:8` should be repeated 6 times because the repeat of the repeat of object with `id:5` and `id:7` in which 3*2 = 6. Now I don't want yet to repeat the objects in the resulting array but simply add a new attribute to each object which says how many times an object should be repeated. As it can be seen in array B object with `id:8: it should have a new attribute called` repeat`and should have the value of`6`. I'm struggling to wrap my head around it.

I tried with loops and recursions but I was never even close to anything.

```
    public function loopOver($data, &$newData, &$repeat, &$previousRepeat, $i){
        $dataCount = count($data);
 
        for( ; $i<$dataCount; $i++){

            if($data[$i]['type']=='repeat'){
                $previousRepeat = $data[$i]['number'];
                $repeat = $repeat * $data[$i]['number'];
                return $this->loopOver($data, $newData, $repeat, $previousRepeat, $i+1);
            }

            if($data[$i]['type']=='close_repeat'){
                $repeat = $repeat/$previousRepeat;
                return $this->loopOver($data, $newData, $repeat, $previousRepeat, $i+1);
            }

            if($i >= $dataCount){
                return $newData;
            }

            $tmpData = $data[$i];
            $tmpData['repeat'] = $repeat;
            $newData [] = $tmpData;

        }
        
    }
```

The above codes returns the correct list but the `repeat` is not accurate.

Comment: Try to share the closest code you ever got. There we can see the logic you are following and give you a hint.

Comment: Updated the post with the code

Comment: If I understand your requirements correctly I will do it this way: (1) Traverse the array, set the multiplier to be 1 (initial value). (2) If you detects type <> repeat and close_repeat, store the data in a temp array, if you detects a repeat, update the multiplier to this new value (old value * new multiplier) and at the same time save the old array,  but if you detects a close repeat, reset the multiplier to 1. (But actually I think your "array type" data processing design is dreadful --- who give you this array ? )

Comment: I mean this is what i'm trying to do. But I'm still struggling with putting it into code.

Comment: Actually, this solved it, but I don't understand why repeat has to be set to 1 on `close_repeat`, shouldn't it be divided by the last multiplication?

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = [
  [
     "id"=>1,
     "type"=>"title",
     "data"=> "Title goes here"
  ],
  [
     "id"=>2,
     "type"=>"repeat",
     "number"=>3,
  ],
  [
     "id"=>3,
     "type"=>"media",
     "data"=> "path to media"
  ],
  [
     "id"=>4,
     "type"=>"close_repeat"
  ],
  [
     "id"=>5,
     "type"=>"repeat",
     "number"=>3,
  ],
  [
     "id"=>6,
     "type"=>"title",
     "data"=> "Title goes here"
  ],
  [
     "id"=>7,
     "type"=>"repeat",
     "number"=>2,
  ],
  [
     "id"=>8,
     "type"=>"text",
     "data"=> "Text goes here"
  ],
  [
     "id"=>9,
     "type"=>"close_repeat"
  ],
  [
     "id"=>10,
     "type"=>"close_repeat"
  ],
  [
     "id"=>11,
     "type"=>"cover",
     "data"=> "Cover data goes here"
  ],
];


$newData = array();
$new_arr = array();
$count_arr = 0;

foreach ($data as $arr) {
  if (key_exists('data', $arr)) {
    $new_arr[$count_arr++] = $arr;
  }
}

$count_arr = 0;
$repeat = 0;
$first_key = array_key_first($new_arr);
$last_key = array_key_last($new_arr);

foreach ($new_arr as $key => $value) {
  $newData[$key] = $value;
  
  // Create repeat key and set value
  if ($key == $first_key) {
    // repeat key value for first arr
    $newData[$count_arr++]['repeat'] = $new_arr[$repeat++]['id'];
  } elseif ($key == $last_key) {
    // repeat key value for last arr (same as first repeat key value)
    $newData[$count_arr++]['repeat'] = $new_arr[$first_key]['id'];
  } else {
    // repeat key value for others array
    $newData[$count_arr++]['repeat'] = $new_arr[$repeat++ - 1]['id'];
  }
  
}

// new data
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newData);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation please?

Comment: what About? The code is simple and I have used the basic functionality of PHP in this code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).